# Wampserver não instala o Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver

Instalei o Wampserver no meu Windows 10, só que o localhost não funcionava, por causa do **IIS Windows**, então configurei o Apache para usar o **localhost:8080**.

Até ai tudo bem, consigo acessar a instalação local do meu wordpress, até acessei o PhpMtAdmin para criar o banco, mas quando chego na parte da instalação do wordpress que tem que colocar no nome do BD, Usuário, Senha... ele não passa dessa página, ou melhor, sempre vai para a tela **"Não foi possível selecionar a base de dados"**

1. No nome do BD eu coloco o nome do Banco.
2. Nome de usuário, coloco root
3. Senha, deixo em branco porque esta assim no arquivo
4. Servidor do banco de dados eu coloco localhost:8080
5. Prefixo da Tabela o padrão wp_

Segue algumas informações do wampserver

- MySQL Version:5.7.19 - Port defined for MySQL: 3308
- MariaDB Version:10.2.8 - Port defined for MariaDB: 3306
- Apache Version:2.4.27
- PHP Version:7.0.23
- Server Software:Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.0.23 - Port defined for Apache: 8080

O que pode está travando a instalação? Ou melhor, pelo que entendi a instalação do Wordpress não consegue se conectar ao banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, coloquei o localhost com a porta do MySQL que era 3308, então ficou **localhost:3308**. Estava colocando localhost:8080